# AngularJS getterSetter shows me the name of function instead of carrying it out

Tags: angularjs

Greeting everybody. I start in AngularJS. I try to use the ng-model-options with "Getter-Setter" but as soon as I try to have a return he writes me the code of function instead of using it.

```js
/**
 * Created by Pierre on 21-03-17.
 */


 function myController($rootScope) {
    var _name = " ";
    //get and setter pour optionSetter
    $rootScope.name = function(nom){
        _name = angular.isDefined(nom) ? nom:_name;
        return _name;
    };
}

angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngSanitize'
]).controller('myController', ['$rootScope', myController]);
```

```html
<form>
    Nom:<input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }" />
</form>
  <p ng-bind="name"></p>
```

And my browser output :

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZfQy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Change view to  `ng-model="name()"`

Comment: nothing changes, except that I cannot enter any more of text in the input